# Where does Git Bash get all its host mappings from?

Tags: windows-8, git-bash, hosts

I'm using Git Bash in Windows 8. I can see it has copied `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` over to `/etc/hosts`. Note that `/etc/hosts` is not a link to `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` - you can prove this to yourself by modifying `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` and seeing that `/etc/hosts` is not immediately modified. My guess is that `/etc/hosts` is copied over from `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` when git bash is launched, but that's really irrelevant to this question.

My real question here is why there are other known hosts which do not appear in either of these files:

```
$ ping host-not-in-files
Pinging host-not-in-files [192.168.3.3] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.3.3: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.3.3: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
^C
```

Where is Git Bash getting the mapping from `host-not-in-files` to `192.168.3.3` from?

**Note: `host-not-in-files` is not a literal string - I could just as well have written `ping bob` or `ping fred` here - it's just intended to be a hostname that cannot be found in either `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` or `/etc/hosts`. I don't want to post the actual string I use in my PC into stackoverflow for security reasons - just the same reason as why `192.168.3.3` is not a real IP address in my network.**

Also note that I have no problems with using the hosts in either `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` or `/etc/hosts` - these are being mapped fine by Git Bash. I just want to know where the other mappings are occurring.

Comment: Are you sure that's a Git Bash version of ping, and not the standard Windows ping.exe?  If it is different, does the Windows ping behave the same way, or does it give you the "could not find host" error?

Answer (score 1):

in your home directory  `cd ~` you have a soft link

`hosts -> /c/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts`

which is not  /etc/hosts (don't know why :))
so if you are admin on your computer use

```
nano ~/hosts        # not /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 0):

This "`host-not-in-files`" entry is [not set by git-for-windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22host-not-in-files%22&type=Issues), and I don't see it in my git 2.8.1 bash session on Windows.

`/etc/hosts` is the exact copy of `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`.

Comment: I have clarified my question.

Comment: @mulllhausen my answer stands: basically, I do not reproduce what you have, so this is specific to your environment.

Comment: obviously its set by my environment. I want to know where its being set.

Comment: @mulllhausen OK. Still searching then. Maybe a side effect from https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/pull/89#issuecomment-158464207?